# Image rotator script not going in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I have an image rotator script that I am making for a client. The only problem that I have with it is that it does not go in order from top to bottom like I would have hoped it would have done.

**The Issue**

The reason that I have a problem with this is that it will take the image and sometimes show the same image back to back with each other which is something that I really do not want. Here is the **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loweman/qa5yk6q7/)** if you want to see what I have so far in action.

**Something that could work**

Is it possible for me to add and `id` to each of the images and then control the order like that?

**HTML**

```
<section class="demo">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <button class="prev">Previous</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/700x700"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.container div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display','inline-block');
}


$('.next').click(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

Thanks so much,
Alex

Comment: The order is "people -> any -> nature -> architecture -> animals -> people (again) -> tech" and it goes round and round.. May I ask for more clarification on what the problem is?

Comment: I think there's an issue with PlaceImg loading the same images in, not with your code. Here's a fiddle using placehold.it with numbers in order: https://jsfiddle.net/qa5yk6q7/1/

Comment: they are not static images. so people and any could be the same image. your code is working correctly

Comment: Yes, you are correct it is placeImg's fault and not my codes I changed the images to placehold.it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I just edited my question and it works fine now.

Comment: now lets just assume that I did want my images to be random how would I do that?

Comment: @Alex you'll have to be more specific on how exactly that would work. _PlaceImg_ is using the same pool of images on every request to `person`. I'm guessing you don't want to repeat images so you'd need a way to reduce the pool of images once one has been selected from the pool. If you're using your own images that's easy. If you're using _PlaceImg_, as easy. You'd likely have to create a hash from each image which would use the image's unique data to create a unique string (id).

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct I am going to be usingy own images and I do want the images to not repeat them selves until they have all been flipped through.

Comment: Then the file name is your unique id and you're good to go. Your file system won't allow two images with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: What is the intention of adding an `id` to control order? To uniquely identify each image or so you can use markup like this: `<div id="1"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="2"></div>`, which would allow you to reorder the images by changing `id` values instead of moving the block of markup for each slide/image.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a id in each div and change your script to:

```
var currentIndex = 0,


items = $('.container div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;


function cycleItems() {
  var item = document.getElementById(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.style.display = 'inline-block';
}


$('.next').click(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

and change the html to:

```
<section class="demo">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <button class="prev">Previous</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="1" style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any"/>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature"/>
    </div>
    <div id="4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/architecture"/>
    </div>
    <div id="5">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals"/>
    </div>
    <div id="6">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div id="7">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I believe this will resolve your problem.